# Random misfires and 2+3 cylinder misfires on 2009 Accord

Tags: honda, accord, misfire, p0300, p030x

I have a 2009 Honda Accord 2.4 L.

It is reporting random misfires and cylinders 2+3 misfires.

There was a thread posted about this same exact problem but was never resolved.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. [Could you please post up the specific codes?](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/1470/675) A freeze frame would be very helpful here, if available. Are the misfires consistent or intermittent? There are a ton of possible reasons for a misfire, so the more information you can provide, the better. Thanks!

Comment: if the plugs coils etc... check out, make sure the battery terminals are clean and tight, the battery is fully charged and try a crank variation relearn. this requires a scantool with bidirectional controls.

Comment: The codes are P0300 P0302 and P0303  The battery is new.  compression is at 150-160 in all cylinders. plugs are new. coils are good. mil light flashes

Comment: Can you actually feel the misfires? Any crank sensor codes?

Comment: No crank sensor codes, yes you can feel the misfire. I guess the next step is to do a leakdown test. Maybe valves or rings are bad

Comment: On this site there was the exact same problem I am having with the exact car but they never answered what the problem was or if it was resolved. it was posted in april. . maybe you could find the post

Comment: I'd check valve adjustment as well. if there's no crank sensor code than you can probably rule out a crank pattern issue.

Answer (score 2):

I second checking valve adjustment. Also, how do your plugs look? We have been replacing pistons & rings under an extended warranty at the dealer for oil consumption issues with many of the 2.4L engines (Accord, CRV, Crosstour). If your car is consuming large amounts of oil between changes it may be something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

**If the MIL is flashing, shut the car off immediately and do not run it until the problems are resolved.  You can cause extensive damage when the MIL is flashing!

If compression is good, the most likely causes are:

Low Fuel Pressure, Vacuum Leak, EGR system malfunction

Less common causes:
Faulty Coil, Faulty Spark Plugs and/or Wires, Camshaft or Crankshaft sensors, Ignition module, Computer